# Defining convection boundary conditions for 1d transient heat equation in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I am currently working on a problem with a hollow cylindrical graphite crucible that will contain liquid aluminum and I am trying to get the transient temperature function using the following heat equation.

$$\frac{1}{a}\frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dT}{dr}\right)$$

I am thinking of using finite difference method to get this temperature function but I am just confused how to define the convective boundary condition on the outside of the crucible in cylindrical coordinates with finite difference.

Comment: What is the BC that you want to use (in words)?

Comment: On the outside surface of the cylindrical graphite crucible, I want to set a convective boundary condition with a heat transfer coefficient of h = 2000 W/m^2K and the ambient temperature is 15 deg C. Hopefully this explains it better and let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

$$q(t,R)=-k\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)_{r=R}=h(T(R)-T_a)$$

Comment: Thank you but I was just wondering how this BC would change as I wanted to do a finite difference method on the hollow graphite cylinder with inner radius Ri and outer radius Ro.